# Is it possible to get large Linkedin profile pic URL?

Tags: android, linkedin-api, socialauth

I'm developing a LinkedIn social login for Android app. After the authentication, I'm getting the profile image URL. But it was too small (w=80px * h=80px). Has there any way to get large image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the original size (the size uploaded by the user) of the profile picture URL like so:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)
```